# Performance: Dispatching an action vs passing as props in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, store, reducers

I have a technical question. I am trying to pass a value from child component to store by using action dispatcher inside my child component. This action dispatcher then updates the state value in the reducer.

Is it advisable to pass value from the child component this way? will it affect the performance of the react app?

Or should I use props to pass from child to parent component and then update the state.

Please advise as I searched a lot about this but didn't get any info.

Answer (score 2):

Problem with passing dispatcher to your child is your child component is not very reusable. I would suggest to pass a callback method to your child which contains the logic of dispatching the event.

Parent:

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {

  loginHandler(){
    ...
    this.props.someMethod();
  }

  render() {
    return {
      ...
      <ChildComponent click="loginHandler"></ChildComponent>
      ...
    }
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    // dispatching plain actions
    ...
    someMethod: () => dispatch({ ... }),
    ...
  }
}
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ParentComponent);
```

Child Component:

```
function ChildComponent({click}) {
  return {
    ...
    <button click={click}></button>
    ...
  }
}
```

Now with this approach your child approach doesn't carry any business logic. It can be used at multiple places.

Comment: thanks for reply. But in this case too, it is dispatching an action. Not from child component but from parent component. so action dispatcher happens either way. My question is, if i can avoid dispatching an action. Instead pass the value from child to parent and somehow ensure parent updates the store. (Without using dispatcher) 

Is this achievable was my question ?

Comment: In order to update store you need to use dispatcher